# If Prometheus pulls absolute metrics values or just difference from previous pull?

Tags: prometheus

Are there any documentation describing details where calculated differences between previous and current metrics values? On client side or on server side or its don't calculated by Prometheus at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus pulls absolute values, and the rate of change is calculated on the Prometheus side.

[This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Ulrq6DxwA) explains in detail.